# Magento 2: Cannot load my library using composer

Tags: magento2, composer

Sorry for the lengthy message.  I just wanted to provide as much information as possible.  I am writing a new module. I have a custom library that I need to load to use in my module.  I have the library classes in `vendor/easyask/easyask_search/lib/EasyAsk/Impl`.  The module is in `app/code/EasyAsk/Search`.

When I try to invoke `EasyAsk\Impl\RemoteFactory`, I get a class does not exist error.  I know the lib files are not autoloaded as I don't see them referenced in vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php file.

**Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

Here is the **composer.json** in my module

```
{
"name": "easyask/module-search",
"description": "A better search module from EasyAsk",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0",
    "magento/module-store": "1.0.0-beta",
    "magento/module-catalog": "1.0.0-beta",
    "magento/module-catalog-search": "1.0.0-beta",
    "magento/module-backend": "1.0.0-beta",
    "magento/module-theme": "1.0.0-beta",
    "magento/framework": "1.0.0-beta",
"easyask/easyask_search": "2.0.0",
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "1.0.0-beta",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"extra": {
    "map": [
        [
            "*",
            "EasyAsk/Search"
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

Here is the **composer.json** from **vendor/easyask/easyask_search** directory

```
{
"name": "easyask/easyask_search",
"type": "magento2-library",
"description": "EasyAsk Search PHP Client Library",
"license": "N/A",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "EasyAsk",
        "homepage": "http://www.easyask.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.2.1",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-hash": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "ext-xmlwriter": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "EasyAsk": "lib"
    }
}
```

}

Part of controller class where I'm trying to inject **RemoteFactory**

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Manager;
use EasyAsk\Impl\RemoteFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{
    /**
     * @var QueryFactory
     */
    private $_queryFactory;

    /**
     * Catalog Layer Resolver
     *
     * @var Resolver
     */
    private $layerResolver;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $_eventManager;

    protected $_remoteFactory;

     /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $catalogSession
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param QueryFactory $queryFactory
     * @param Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $catalogSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Manager $eventManager,
        RemoteFactory $remoteFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $catalogSession, $storeManager, $queryFactory, $layerResolver);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_remoteFactory = $remoteFactory;
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What version of 2.0 are you running (1.0.0-beta)? You should take a look at the latest 2.0.x version because there are some changes to composer.json. Also take a look at http://alankent.me/2015/10/13/magento-2-extension-experience-quick-note/

Comment: I am using the beta version.  Let me download the latest version and try it again. Thanks.

Comment: I downloaded 2.0.2, installed it, did all the upgrades, made sure the site is working as expected.  Added my module and made sure the controller class is getting called.  I tried psr-4 approach without any luck.  Maybe my approach to this problem is wrong.  Let me state what I am trying to do.  I want somebody to comment on the correct approach. I have a module that has all the stuff (blocks, controller, models etc), in Magento 1 I had the library files (bunch of files that makes a curl request to a server and parse the JSON response into php objects) in lib directory.  Based on my

Comment: understanding I tried to add the lib files in vendor.  that did not work.  After further reading I placed the files in <magento install dir>/lib.  The structure is lib/easyask/easyask/lib/EasyAsk/Impl.  I have composer.json file in lib/easyask/easyask directory that has     "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "EasyAsk\\": "lib/"
        }
    }.  Is this the right approach?  BTW, this did not work either.  When i did setup:di:compile, I get Class does not exist error for EasyAsk\Imple\RemoteFactory.  Should I just place the files in app/code/EasyAsk/lib directory?

Answer (score 0):

if you installed the library via composer, I can only see one potential problem on first sight.

the psr-0 namespace declaration must have (I think) a trailing backslash (which also must be escaped). So it would look like this:

```
"psr-0": {
    "EasyAsk\\": "lib"
}
```

The file for the class in your library should then be located in `lib/EasyAsk/Impl/RemoteFactory.php` and have the namespace `EasyAsk\Impl` and the class name `RemoteFactory`

you could also leave out the type `magento2-library` then which would default to the library and just use the default composer autoloading mechanism.

you can find further information on composer psr-0 autoloading here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

to see if your library is correctly loaded via composer you can also look into the file `vendor/composer/autoload_psr0.php` (or smth similar). There should be an entry for this.

To recompile the composer autoloading files you can execute the following command in your Magento 2 root dir: `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Thank you @david-verholen for the response.  I made the change in the namespace declaration, but without any luck.  I still don't see the entry in vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php.

Comment: I think the trailing backslash is required when using PSR4, not with PSR0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21463602/616307.

Comment: @Srinivas After making changes to your modules, make sure to update things. You can't just change it inside the vendor folder and expect it to work; therefore you need the composer dump-autoload command to recompile things as mentioned above. I would suggest to go with PSR4 anyway, in my opinion its easier to follow the paths when using it, and easier to make use of it in composer.json.

Comment: @stefandoorn Thanks for your suggestion, I changed it to psr4.  Yes whenever I make any changes I have been doing composer dump-autoload. I feel I am making a very simple mistake in the code and it still is not working. Here are the changes I made:1. Changed the vendor directory to easyask/easyask. 2. composer.json in vendor/easyask/easyask has     "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "EasyAsk\\": "lib/EasyAsk/"
        }
    }  3. I changed the reference in module composer.json to point to easyask/easyask.  I don't see easyask reference in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php.

Comment: using psr-4 is most likely the better and easier approach. Did you change your directory Structure in your lib as well? with psr-4 defined like in your psr-0 Example, the Classfile would have to be in the directory lib/Impl/RemoteFactory.php

Comment: Yes, I did.  The class file is in lib/EasyAsk/Impl directory.  I just updated my comment.  I expect composer to go through all the directories and aggregate the composer.json files.  Do I have to explicitly state somewhere  for composer to pickup composer.json file from vendor/easyask/easyask directory?

Comment: no, running composer dumpautoload should add an entry to the autoload_psr4.php file. Currently I'm also not able to find a mistake here why it shouldn't work. Did you update composer with composer selfupdate? Just a long shot :o Composer would have to be really outdated for that beeing an issue

Comment: you could also try to run composer validate in your libraries root directory although I cannot really find a mistake there

Comment: I did a composer self-update.  Here is the output ~]# composer self-update
Updating to version 00d12526ec966cc75817c0bf43dd55c76dcbf5c0.
    Downloading: 100%
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 9e623f50e7c883a1108352dd61c3d77a65e41130
I also ran composer validate in vendor/easyask/easyask without any errors.  I did composer dump-autoload after update and still no luck :-(

Comment: just came accross an old composer issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1710 since your autoloading directive does still not show up in the vendor/composer/autoload_*.php files my next long shot idea from this issue would be to delete the lib folder from vendor and reinstall it with composer install/update

Comment: I wish I can start a chat with you @DavidVerholen.  I am new to stackexchange and I don't have enough points to start one.  Still working on this without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how Magento 2 itself did this in `Magento_Base` modules' composer.json, inside `extra` key. I was able to utilise the same syntax for a php library in one of my modules. For reference, I just pasted that chunk of code below:

```
"extra": {
    "component_paths": {
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        "components/jquery": [
            "lib/web/jquery.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
        ],
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
        "components/jqueryui": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js",
        "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
    },
    "map": [
        [
            ".htaccess",
            ".htaccess"
        ],
        [
            ".htaccess.sample",
            ".htaccess.sample"
        ],
        [
            ".php_cs",
            ".php_cs"
        ],
        [
            ".travis.yml",
            ".travis.yml"
        ],
        [
            ".user.ini",
            ".user.ini"
        ],
        [
            "CHANGELOG.md",
            "CHANGELOG.md"
        ],
        [
            "CONTRIBUTING.md",
            "CONTRIBUTING.md"
        ],
        [
            "COPYING.txt",
            "COPYING.txt"
        ],
        [
            "Gruntfile.js.sample",
            "Gruntfile.js.sample"
        ],
        [
            "ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md",
            "ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md"
        ],
        [
            "LICENSE.txt",
            "LICENSE.txt"
        ],
        [
            "LICENSE_AFL.txt",
            "LICENSE_AFL.txt"
        ],
        [
            "app/.htaccess",
            "app/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "app/autoload.php",
            "app/autoload.php"
        ],
        [
            "app/bootstrap.php",
            "app/bootstrap.php"
        ],
        [
            "app/design/adminhtml/Magento",
            "app/design/adminhtml/Magento"
        ],
        [
            "app/design/frontend/Magento",
            "app/design/frontend/Magento"
        ],
        [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php",
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        [
            "app/etc/di.xml",
            "app/etc/di.xml"
        ],
        [
            "app/functions.php",
            "app/functions.php"
        ],
        [
            "bin/.htaccess",
            "bin/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "bin/magento",
            "bin/magento"
        ],
        [
            "dev/.htaccess",
            "dev/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/api-functional/.gitignore",
            "dev/tests/api-functional/.gitignore"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/api-functional/_files",
            "dev/tests/api-functional/_files"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/api-functional/config",
            "dev/tests/api-functional/config"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/api-functional/framework",
            "dev/tests/api-functional/framework"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit.xml.dist",
            "dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit.xml.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento",
            "dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/.gitignore",
            "dev/tests/functional/.gitignore"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/.htaccess.sample",
            "dev/tests/functional/.htaccess.sample"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/bootstrap.php",
            "dev/tests/functional/bootstrap.php"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/composer.json",
            "dev/tests/functional/composer.json"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/credentials.xml.dist",
            "dev/tests/functional/credentials.xml.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/etc",
            "dev/tests/functional/etc"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/isolation.php",
            "dev/tests/functional/isolation.php"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/lib",
            "dev/tests/functional/lib"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/phpunit.xml.dist",
            "dev/tests/functional/phpunit.xml.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/tests",
            "dev/tests/functional/tests"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/testsuites/Magento",
            "dev/tests/functional/testsuites/Magento"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/functional/utils",
            "dev/tests/functional/utils"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/integration/.gitignore",
            "dev/tests/integration/.gitignore"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/integration/etc",
            "dev/tests/integration/etc"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/integration/framework",
            "dev/tests/integration/framework"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist",
            "dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento",
            "dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/integration/tmp",
            "dev/tests/integration/tmp"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/.gitignore",
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/.gitignore"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/framework",
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/framework"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/jsTestDriver.php.dist",
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/jsTestDriver.php.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/jsTestDriverOrder.php",
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/jsTestDriverOrder.php"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/run_js_tests.php",
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/run_js_tests.php"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/testsuite/lib",
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/testsuite/lib"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/testsuite/mage",
            "dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/testsuite/mage"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/js/jasmine",
            "dev/tests/js/jasmine"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/static/.gitignore",
            "dev/tests/static/.gitignore"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/static/framework",
            "dev/tests/static/framework"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/static/get_github_changes.php",
            "dev/tests/static/get_github_changes.php"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/static/phpunit-all.xml.dist",
            "dev/tests/static/phpunit-all.xml.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/static/phpunit.xml.dist",
            "dev/tests/static/phpunit.xml.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento",
            "dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/unit/.gitignore",
            "dev/tests/unit/.gitignore"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/unit/framework",
            "dev/tests/unit/framework"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist",
            "dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tests/unit/tmp",
            "dev/tests/unit/tmp"
        ],
        [
            "dev/tools",
            "dev/tools"
        ],
        [
            "dev/travis",
            "dev/travis"
        ],
        [
            "index.php",
            "index.php"
        ],
        [
            "lib/.htaccess",
            "lib/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "lib/internal/LinLibertineFont",
            "lib/internal/LinLibertineFont"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/FormData.js",
            "lib/web/FormData.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/MutationObserver.js",
            "lib/web/MutationObserver.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/blank.html",
            "lib/web/blank.html"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/css",
            "lib/web/css"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/es6-collections.js",
            "lib/web/es6-collections.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/extjs",
            "lib/web/extjs"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/fonts",
            "lib/web/fonts"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/fotorama",
            "lib/web/fotorama"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/i18n",
            "lib/web/i18n"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/images",
            "lib/web/images"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/jquery.js",
            "lib/web/jquery.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/jquery",
            "lib/web/jquery"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/knockoutjs",
            "lib/web/knockoutjs"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/legacy-build.min.js",
            "lib/web/legacy-build.min.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/less",
            "lib/web/less"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/lib",
            "lib/web/lib"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/mage",
            "lib/web/mage"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/magnifier",
            "lib/web/magnifier"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/matchMedia.js",
            "lib/web/matchMedia.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/modernizr",
            "lib/web/modernizr"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/moment-timezone-with-data.js",
            "lib/web/moment-timezone-with-data.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/moment.js",
            "lib/web/moment.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/prototype",
            "lib/web/prototype"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/requirejs",
            "lib/web/requirejs"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/scriptaculous",
            "lib/web/scriptaculous"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/spacer.gif",
            "lib/web/spacer.gif"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/tiny_mce",
            "lib/web/tiny_mce"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/underscore.js",
            "lib/web/underscore.js"
        ],
        [
            "lib/web/varien",
            "lib/web/varien"
        ],
        [
            "nginx.conf.sample",
            "nginx.conf.sample"
        ],
        [
            "package.json.sample",
            "package.json.sample"
        ],
        [
            "php.ini.sample",
            "php.ini.sample"
        ],
        [
            "phpserver",
            "phpserver"
        ],
        [
            "pub/.htaccess",
            "pub/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "pub/.user.ini",
            "pub/.user.ini"
        ],
        [
            "pub/cron.php",
            "pub/cron.php"
        ],
        [
            "pub/errors",
            "pub/errors"
        ],
        [
            "pub/get.php",
            "pub/get.php"
        ],
        [
            "pub/index.php",
            "pub/index.php"
        ],
        [
            "pub/media/.htaccess",
            "pub/media/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "pub/media/customer/.htaccess",
            "pub/media/customer/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess",
            "pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "pub/media/import",
            "pub/media/import"
        ],
        [
            "pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess",
            "pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "pub/opt",
            "pub/opt"
        ],
        [
            "pub/static.php",
            "pub/static.php"
        ],
        [
            "pub/static/.htaccess",
            "pub/static/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "setup",
            "setup"
        ],
        [
            "var/.htaccess",
            "var/.htaccess"
        ],
        [
            "vendor/.htaccess",
            "vendor/.htaccess"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.